# Как найти значение в БД sqlite Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```
get = nimber[0] 
print(get) #n4iub44b5v2bhjb4234v5hg2v3
exists = pursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM srid WHERE {} IN srid""".format(f'{get}')).fetchall()
```

я испробовал все методы WHERE но не могу найти значение переменной get. таблица называется srid а колонка в ней nimber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exists = pursor.execute(f"SELECT nimber FROM srid WHERE nimber = '{get}'")
```

сам спросил, сам ответил...